# How do I only allow the ajax request if the javascript calling is on the same server as the PHP file?

Tags: ajax

How do I make it so an ajax request can only be executed if the JS and PHP files are on the same server?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: The question does not make sense. Javascript is on the client side, therefore it can't be on the same server as the PHP file (unless the client happens to *be* the server)

Comment: Well read that it is not possible to do a ajax post call cross domain as default - but want to be absolutely sure it is not possible.

Comment: Think of google analytics, it calls a JS file hosted by google.
It also makes sure it will only work for the domain registered with that account.

I'm trying sort of the same thing. I'm hosting a JS file that other websites can call, but the script will only run if URL the call is made from matches the URL given in a database for that user (which is found via a key that is given also)

Comment: But (I believe) you can use the same GA script on any of your websites. The end-user is the one ultimately executing the script, and therefore it's impossible to (reliably) determine which site the user is currently visiting without the cooperation of the webmasters maintaining the page.

Comment: In other words, if another webmaster simply copies the script (key included) to his or her website, you cannot reliably determine if the user calling the script is visiting the first or the second website.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you can't.

The best you can do is put up a roadblock that is easy to get around.  So if you are doing this only to *discourage* other people directly accessing your AJAX APIs without going through your Javascript, then it may be sufficient to do something like check the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` server variable.  But this is easy to work around.

If you are doing this for security, the simple answer is that it's not possible.

When designing your internal AJAX API you have to simply remember that anything that your Javascript can request, an external client (such as a robot) could also request.  So, don't divulge any information you wouldn't want anyone else to be able to see, or allow the request to perform any actions you wouldn't want anyone else to be able to perform.

If need to provide access only to authenticated users, then you need to apply the same authentication to your AJAX API as you would for the rest of your site, as it can just as easily be requested by a 3rd party as the rest of your site.

Comment: How about limiting it in your .htacces?

Comment: @SvenB no, you can't do anything at the server level.

Think of it this way: you're allowing anybody in the world access to your API and giving them the code (your website and its Javascript) to do it with. You cannot control if they modify this code or make direct requests as either way, the requests are coming from their machine.  You can't distinguish. The most you could do is obfuscate - make it difficult for them to understand how your code is doing it - but this is of limited benefit, and developer tools still makes it pretty easy for them to see how it's happening.